# SQL Server : Row to Column Interchange

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My sample data

```
Month Name    MaterialName                                Qty
August        M.Sand(Premium M sand concrete)             0.000
December      M.Sand(Premium M sand Plaster -THRIVENI)    24.950
January       M.Sand(Premium M sand concrete)             527.730
January       20MM                                        68.730
January       M.Sand(Premium M sand Plaster -THRIVENI)    333.040
January       12MM                                        41.480
January       6MM                                         135.000
January       GSB                                         78.300
January       TP SAND BAG                                 55.000
November      M.Sand(Premium M sand concrete)             45.000
October      20MM                                         30.000
September    M.Sand(Premium M sand concrete)              40.000
```

Expexted Result:

```
Month Name | M.Sand(Premium M sand concrete) | M.Sand(Premium M sand Plaster -THRIVENI) | 20MM      
August     |         0.000           |      0.000               | 0.000
December   |         0.000           |      24.950              | 0.000
January    |         527.730             |      0.000               | 68.730

etc....
```

Please give suitable solution for above.
I have a result as shown here in this screenshot:

[image]

But I want data like this:

[image]

My query :

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, TripDate) [Month Name],
       MM.MaterialName,
       ISNULL(SUM([NetWeight]), 0) Qty
FROM [TRANS].[tblWeighBridgeEntry] WB
LEFT JOIN MAS.tblMaterialMaster MM ON MM.MaterialID = WB.RefMaterialId
WHERE TripDate IS NOT NULL
  AND TripDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(M, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), 0)
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, TripDate),
         RefMaterialId,
         MaterialName
```

Comment: It's good programming practice to qualify all columns when more then 1 table is involved. Does TripDate mean WB.TripDate or MM.Tripdate?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Use `PIVOT()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this :

```
SELECT 
    MonthName [Month Name]
,   SUM(CASE WHEN MaterialName = 'M.Sand(Premium M sand concrete)' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) [M.Sand(Premium M sand concrete)]
,   SUM(CASE WHEN MaterialName = 'M.Sand(Premium M sand Plaster -THRIVENI)' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) [M.Sand(Premium M sand Plaster-THRIVEN)]
,   SUM(CASE WHEN MaterialName = '20MM' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) [20MM]
-- ......... etc 
FROM (
    SELECT  
        DATENAME(MONTH,TripDate) [MonthName]
    ,   MM.MaterialName
    ,   SUM([NetWeight]) Qty 
    FROM 
        [TRANS].[tblWeighBridgeEntry] WB
    LEFT JOIN MAS.tblMaterialMaster MM ON MM.MaterialID = WB.RefMaterialId
    WHERE 
        TripDate  >=  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(M, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), 0) 
    GROUP BY 
        DATENAME(MONTH, TripDate)
    ,   MaterialName 
) D 
GROUP BY 
    MonthName
```

You just need to get the exact match of MaterialName (in my example above, I've tried to copy what you have in the picture, but this might have some errors), and just find, get, sum. You can do the same on all columns, or you can use PIVOT to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH,TripDate) [Month Name],MM.MaterialName, ISNULL(SUM([NetWeight]),0) Qty
INTO #DataSource
FROM [TRANS].[tblWeighBridgeEntry] WB
LEFT JOIN MAS.tblMaterialMaster MM ON MM.MaterialID = WB.RefMaterialId
WHERE TripDate IS NOT NULL AND  TripDate  >=  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(M, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), 0) 
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, TripDate),RefMaterialId,MaterialName 


DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @ColumnNames = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + MaterialName + ']'
        FROM #DataSource
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
   ,1
   ,1
   ,''
);

SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = N'
select ' + @ColumnNames + '
from ##DataSource
PIVOT 
(
    MAX([Qty]) FOR [key] IN (' + @ColumnNames + ')
) PVT
FOR JSON PATH;
';


EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```